# Why does the same if condition work one time and another time doesn't?

Tags: bash

Hi Stackoverflow community.

I have a question to (probably sporadic) problem.

A bash if-condition for non-equal strings yields one time results another time the error message "[[: command not found".

Sample code of test.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash

arg1=$1

echo -e "arg1: " $arg1

if  [[ $1 != "test" ]] && [[ $1 != "testing" ]]; then
        echo "test1"
fi
if  [[ $1 != "test" ]] && [[ $1 != "testing" ]]; then
        echo "test2"
fi
```

output:

```
$ ./test.sh foo
arg1:  foo
test1
./test.sh: line 10:  [[: command not found
```

As you see the second echo command will never be reached.

I tested the snippet on MacOS bash (GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)) and on Linux bash (GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)) and could confirm that error every time.

(my best guess was that there some kind of encoding problem but I could not confirm that yet).

Thank you in advance for any help and/or pointers.

Comment: It's unrelated but change "#! /bin/bash" to "#!/bin/bash"

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the syntax as such. One reason could be your `/bin/bash` is not really bash, but could be a minimal `sh` shell, but you claim it otherwise

Comment: It works for me with `GNU bash, version 4.3.46(1)-release (x86_64-slackware-linux-gnu)`

Comment: @gbajson: Spaces are allowed between `#!` and the actual interpreter

Comment: Add "set -x" in order to see values of the variables.

Comment: Thanks @Inian, I learnt something new today!

Comment: Couldn't reproduce on mac: `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)`, I see test1 and test2

Comment: thx @gbajson. output with set -x : `+ arg1=foo
+ echo -e 'arg1: ' foo
arg1:  foo
+ [[ foo != \t\e\s\t ]]
+ [[ foo != \t\e\s\t\i\n\g ]]
+ echo test1
test1
+ [[ foo != \t\e\s\t ]]
+ ' [[' foo '!=' testing ']]'
./test.sh: line 12:  [[: command not found`

Comment: See how the last `[[` is printed as `' [['`, unlike all the others? The space before it is probably a non-standard space character, such as a non-breaking space.

Comment: @I0b0 you are right it is a \x{A0} non-break space from the unicode ... must have typed it by accident

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @gbajson and @I0b0 the reason was found:

Error on my part I included an non-break space (Oct 0240, Dec 160, Hex 0xA0, HTML  ) in line 11 right before "[[".